# Improving Neural Network Model Accuracy with Initial Poor Classifications and Clustering

Tags: neural-networks, classification, clustering, accuracy

I have a dataset consisting of 52 files, each classified as 'yes' or 'no' for 22 different attributes based on specific subparts, not the entire content. After tokenizing, converting non-generic namings, and filtering, I generated Ngrams for each file, resulting in varying counts (e.g., File A has 4000 NGrams). The file index and multiplexed attribute values for each file are stored, resulting in a dataset for training a neural network model.

However, the initial data classification is not accurate enough, impacting the model's performance. To refine these classifications, I applied clustering techniques to group similar X values. The goal is to use these clusters to enhance the initial Y values assigned to each record.

I attempted to assign refined Y values using `np.bincount(cluster_data[:, 101:122].flatten()).argmax()`, but this resulted in all Y values being 0 ('no'). My intention is to utilize the initial poor classifications for each file as a starting point and leverage clustering to improve accuracy.

Is there a more effective way to utilize the initial classifications and clustering to assign refined Y values, considering that each file represents a basket with multiple attributes. Assume each file is a basket containing a set of objects and each basket has different objects with different colors. The Y attributes are selected same for all the elements in the basket say for example RED, BIG, BALL (assume there are 3 attributes), or YELLOW, SMALL, CUBE. Normally, I want to have multiple Y values, like not single set of Y values for a basket (list of ngrams).

Thank you for your time and consideration. I genuinely appreciate any guidance or suggestions you can provide to help overcome this challenge. If there are alternative approaches or methods that may be more effective in refining initial classifications and utilizing clustering in this context, your insights would be invaluable. Looking forward to learning from the community's expertise.
Thank you again.
Ferda